# How to make 3 parameters selection and then execute, and not with each selection?

Tags: manipulate

```
Manipulate[{u*v}, Row[{Control[{u, 0, 1}], Control[{v, 0, 1}]}], 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Up]
```

Q1.- How to select the operation *, +, - or /? in the first parameter of Manipulate

Q2.- AND how to force Manipulate/MAthematica to WAIT that I modify various paramenters ( u , v and operation) to execute the operation, AND NOT make the operation in every change I made in u, and in every change of v, and in every change of "+-*/" ?  . Iwant to select u, v and operation, and THEN (only whe I push a buttom or similar) execute with the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContinuousAction` will prevent evaluation. Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{u, ( f /. lst), v, "=", f[u, v]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Kartika"}], {{f, Plus}, lst}, 
 Row[{Control[{u, 0, 1}], Control[{v, 0, 1}]}], 
 ControlType -> {SetterBar, VerticalSlider, VerticalSlider}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Up, LabelStyle -> {Blue, 25}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False, 
 Initialization -> (lst = {Plus -> "+", 
     Times -> "\[Times]", (#1 - #2 &) -> "-"})]
```

[image]

Comment: But the solution by @ubpdqn does not wait until the three parameters are changed to change the dynamic part.