# How to put the labels in the minimun and maximun option in the slide verticals? Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I like this, but.. .. how could I put the labels to know +- over where value I are moving?

for examples, between 0 and 8.

```
 Manipulate[{u*v}, Row[{Control[{u, 0, 1}], Control[{v, 0, 1}]}], 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Up]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
Manipulate[If[a == a, ToExpression[ToString@u <> s <> ToString@v]],
           Row[{Control[{u, 0., 1., VerticalSlider}],
                Control[{v, 0., 1., VerticalSlider}],
                Column[{Control[{s, {"+", "-", "*", "/"}, Setter}], 
                        Button["Calc", a = ! a]}]}], 
           Initialization -> (a = True), 
           TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

More on that:

```
ValueThumbSlider[v_] := ValueThumbSlider[v, {0, 1}];
ValueThumbSlider[Dynamic[var_], {min_, max_}] := 
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[If[! NumberQ[var], var = min]; {0, var}, (var = Last[#]) &],
  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Line[{{0, min}, {0, max}}],
    Dynamic[{Text[var, {1.5, var}, {0, -1}], 
      Polygon[{Offset[{0, 0}, {0, var}], Offset[{-5, -5}, {0, var}], 
        Offset[{-5, 5}, {0, var}]}]}]},
   ImageSize -> {30, 300}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {min, max}},
   PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, 1}, None},
   AspectRatio -> 10, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   Ticks -> {None, {min, max}}],
  {{0, min}, {0, max}}, Appearance -> None]; Panel@
 DynamicModule[{x, y, s}, 
  Column[{Row[{ValueThumbSlider[Dynamic@x], 
      ValueThumbSlider[Dynamic@y], 
      Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic@s, {"+", "-", "*", "/"}]}]}], 
    Dynamic@ToExpression[ToString@x <> ToString@s <> ToString@y]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like it, it´s what iI wanted, and... for label de limits? as http://sensa.square7.ch/lims-vert-slider-.sna040.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5341/193

Comment: you solved me one problem, but I think you mistake the post...  and this is the reply to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45792/how-to-make-3-parameters-selection-and-then-execute-and-not-with-each-selection/45817?noredirect=1#45817

Comment: How to add any similar to see the labels

(customSlider[#1, " i= ", -11, 11, 1] &),

to your code?